# Trying to call specific function on specific page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is doing my nut in.
I want to call a function on a specific page. The actual function seems to be working correctly preventing users in submitting pictures under a specific dimension.
The issues is to identify the page correctly so this function only runs for that page. At the moment the function is just being called anywhere media needs to be uploaded.
code below for your perusal:

```
add_action( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'filter_media_pages' );

function filter_media_pages()
{
    if(is_page($page = 'add-new-propety.php'))
      add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'block_small_images_upload' ); 
}

function block_small_images_upload( $file )
{       

// Mime type with dimensions, check to exit earlier
$mimes = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' );

if( !in_array( $file['type'], $mimes ) )
    return $file;
//Adjust dimensions    
$img = getimagesize( $file['tmp_name'] );
$minimum = array( 'width' => 1170, 'height' => 786 );

if ( $img[0] < $minimum['width'] )
    $file['error'] = 
        'Image too small. Minimum width is ' 
        . $minimum['width'] 
        . 'px. Uploaded image width is ' 
        . $img[0] . 'px';

elseif ( $img[1] < $minimum['height'] )
    $file['error'] = 
        'Image too small. Minimum height is ' 
        . $minimum['height'] 
        . 'px. Uploaded image height is ' 
        . $img[1] . 'px';

return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This jumps out at me:

```
if(is_page($page = 'add-new-propety.php'))
    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'block_small_images_upload' );
```

In this case, you're running `is_page()` on the value of the assignment to `$page`, right? Shouldn't it be like this:

```
if(is_page('add-new-propety.php'))
    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'block_small_images_upload' );
```

Edit: Nevermind, the value should be correct anyway, as the value of an assignment in PHP is the assigned value...

But I don't think you can give a filename directly to `is_page()`, it should probably be the slug, ID or title. Or do you want to check the template that is used?

Comment: I have tried title, slug, ID, the current value. Just seems to ignore the     IF() statement and executes.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an action named "wp_handle_upload_prefilter", only a filter?